# c# jagged array getter and setter

Tags: c#, setter, getter, getter-setter

I have a:

```
private bool[][] field
{
    get { return allfields[allfields.Count - 1]; }
    set { allfields.Add(value); generation++; }
}
```

and a:

```
if (field[x][y])
{
    field[x][y] = false;
}
else
{
    field[x][y] = true;
}
```

the if-clause seems to be working properly but the setter is not called in any way while setting... Is there any Idea of how to solve this (e.g. better setter) or at least a reason for this problem?

Thanks for help

P.S.:

```
field = nextfield.Clone() as bool[][];
```

is calling the setter...

Comment: You are not setting the property - you are setting an array element within the property, so your setter will never be called. It's not clear how to fix it, because it's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Please can you edit your question to describe your actual aim?

Comment: what this code is intended to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better approach is to use Indexer property as a public accessor to the array

```
class BoolArray
{
   public bool this[int raw, int column]
   {
       get
       {
           // access internal jugged array 
           if (_data[raw] == null)
           {
               return false;
           }

           return _data[raw][column];   
       }

       set
       {
          if (_data[raw] == null)
          {
             _data[raw] = new bool[Columns];
          }

          _data[raw][column] = value;

       } 
   }

   // Using a jugged array as storage
   private bool _data[][];
   ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually you are calling getter to return an instance of `bool[][]` and then assign (with `=` operator) the value in the array by index (`[]` operator).

Then you call setter only if you are using `field` in the left part of assign operator but not in `[]` operator that have more priority and called earler.

Then in `field[x][y] = false;` string we have next priority:

1. Property getter
2. First `[]` operator
3. Second `[]` operator
4. `=` operator

And in the `field = nextfield.Clone() as bool[][];` line we have next priority:

1. `.` operator
2. `()` operator
3. `as` operator
4. `=` operator
5. property setter